# Request Manager Helper class for Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, helper

I am working on creating an helper class for alamofire for one of my project. The objective of the helper class is to:

- Centralize all the alamofire requests to a single class.
- All the necessary things needed for sending the request would be centralized, for example checking whether user has access token if not get one, defining base url in the class and creating the routes for requests using the base url.

I have come up with the following class as of now,import Foundation

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class AFManager {

static let baseApiUrl = "Base URL here"

class func request(type type: Alamofire.Method, requestPath: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, encoding: ParameterEncoding = .JSON,
                        headers: [String: String], onSuccess: (JSON) -> Void, onFailure: (NSError) -> Void) {

    Alamofire.request(type, baseAPIURL + requestPath, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isFailure {
            onFailure(response.result.error!)
        } else {
            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
            onSuccess(json)
        }
    }   
  }  
}
```

But I am not sure whether the above class is efficient enough to handle what I am trying to achieve. Please let me know if I am missing something, what are the things that I need to take care of when creating an helper class like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to handle retry attempts too.

Comment: @RuchiraRandana Hey Ruchira, thanks for the suggestion, I will add the method to retry requests. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: hi can you send me that helper class for learning refrence ??

Answer (score 0):

In addition to handling retry attempts, I would also like to point out some other factors that you might like to consider.

- Handling cancellation of requests: You might want to cancel requests after adding it as a request.
- Caching of resources such as images.
- Adding priority to request. Some request might need higher priority than others.
- Setting a maxmimum number of requests which will run concurrently.
  ie: You don't want the app to start downloading 100 images
  asynchronously!

Hope this helps.